# Dynamic pivoting in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am in desperate need of SQL-Wizard's advice.

## Input

I have 2 tables with the following structure:

Table 1 - 'tv':

```sql
CREATE TABLE tv (
    tv_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    clip_id BIGINT,
    date DATE,
    ...
);
```

| tv_id | clip_id | date | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | ... |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-01-02 | ... |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-01-02 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Table2 - 'aud_metrics':

```sql
CREATE TABLE aud_metrics (
    tv_id BIGINT,
    aud VARCHAR(3),
    age VARCHAR(8),
    tvr1 NUMERIC,
    tvr2 NUMERIC,
    ots NUMERIC,
    PRIMARY KEY (tv_id, aud, age),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tv
        FOREIGN KEY(tv_id)
            REFERENCES tv(tv_id)
);
```

| tv_id | aud | age | tvr1 | tvr2 | ots |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | all | 18_plus | 0.63 | 0.71 | 23.5 |
| 1 | all | 25_plus | 0.55 | 0.77 | 21.7 |
| 1 | m | 18_plus | 0.48 | 0.74 | 15.8 |
| 1 | m | 25_plus | 0.43 | 0.79 | 12.3 |
| 1 | w | 18_plus | 0.81 | 0.77 | 14.6 |
| 1 | w | 25_plus | 0.61 | 0.73 | 22.8 |
| 2 | all | 18_plus | 0.59 | 0.74 | 66.6 |
| 2 | all | 25_plus | 0.66 | 0.75 | 42.1 |
| 2 | m | 18_plus | 0.73 | 0.72 | 11.1 |
| 2 | m | 25_plus | 0.92 | 0.73 | 22.2 |
| 2 | w | 18_plus | 0.12 | 0.75 | 33.3 |
| 2 | w | 25_plus | 0.72 | 0.77 | 44.4 |

## Desired output

And I have to pivot this data to the nastiest possible structure:

| tv_id | date | all_18_plus_tvr1 | all_18_plus_tvr2 | all_18_plus_ots | all_25_plus_tvr1 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 0.63 | 0.71 | 23.5 | 0.55 | ... |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 | 0.59 | 0.74 | 66.6 | 0.66 | ... |

Both tables are huge: 4.6 million rows in table1 and 31 million rows in table2.
The scariest part - both tables will become 20 times bigger very soon.
Columns of the output must be generated dynamically based on values in columns aud_metrics.aud and aud_metrics.age.

I tried the obvious solution - join tables on tv_id, unnest columns tvr1, tvr2 and ots -> then pivot using crosstab.

Saving unpivoted data as table cost me 50 GB of space and a lot of waiting time, i don't think that's correct approach.

I tried another method - join 3 different crosstabs - one for each value columns (trp1, trp2 and ots) - it takes an insane amount of time to write and run this query and I will have to rewrite it when new data will appear.

Perhaps there is a way to write some magic function that will construct and run the SQL query?
And then save it in a new table / append it to an existing table?

Comment: Please update the question with the DDL for the tables. Details about primary keys, foreign keys, indexes, and constraints on column values should be included. Regarding column values, are the categories for _aud_ and _age_ limited to the values shown? If the values are static, are they enforced by check or foreign key constraints?

Comment: @JohnH, thank you for your time! I've updated the question with DDL, categories for aud and age are not limited nor enforced by constraints